# Loop in a html form erb using ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, erb, turbolinks

I would like to build a form where the field name are type1, type2, type3 ...to type10, size1, size2, size3...to size10 etc.

I need to render them in a text field so that user can enter values for them. 
I do not want to manually key in each one of them because there must be some loop iterator I can use. I am aware of each method, but I just want to create a loop to loop through type1 to type10. How can I achieve this?

```
 <div class="field" id="type1">
    <%= f.label :type1 %>
    <%= f.select :type1 ,['text','barcode']%>
 </div> 

 <div class="field" id="type2">
    <%= f.label :type2 %>
    <%= f.select :type2 ,['text','barcode']%>
 </div> 

<div class="field" id="barcode_type1">
    <%= f.label :barcode_type1 %>
    <%= f.text_field :barcode_type1 %>
    </div> 

<div class="field" id="barcode_type2">
    <%= f.label :barcode_type2 %>
    <%= f.text_field :barcode_type2 %>
    </div>
```

Any suggestions?

updates:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){


if ($('#type1').find('option:selected').val() != "barcode")
  {
   $('#barcode_type1').hide();
   $("#barcode_type1").attr('disabled','disabled');
  }
  else
  {
     $("#barcode_type1").removeAttr('disabled');
     $('#barcode_type1').show();
  }

$('#type1').on('change', function(){
  if ($('#type1').find('option:selected').val() != "barcode")
  {
   $('#barcode_type1').hide();
   $("#barcode_type1").attr('disabled','disabled');
  }
  else
  {
     $("#barcode_type1").removeAttr('disabled');
     $('#barcode_type1').show();
  }
})

});
```

If I set div id to id = "type1", the JS runs fine. If I use "type#{i}" using the loop, the JS stopeed working. Is there a solution for this. 
And I would also like to loop type 1 to type 10 and barcode_type1 to barcode_type10 in the Javascript too. Is there a way to do it efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
<% for i in 1..10 do %>
  <div class="field" id="type#{i}"
    <%= f.label "type#{i}" %>
    <%= f.select "type#{i}", ["text", "barcode"] %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: how about in jquery? how do I do the looping of variables with index at the back?

Comment: For jQuery you can use `for(i = 0; i < 11; i++) {  #do something }`

Comment: so now i am able to create the form nicely. However, the corresponding Jquery stopped working. I checked the browser inspector, the div id become "type#{i}" instead of "type1", I think jquery dont work if we put expression in the div id?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use each loop as you mentioned, but not for loop.

```
<% (1..10).each do |i| %>
    <div class="field" id="type#{i}">
        <%= f.label "type#{i}" %>
        <%= f.select "type#{i}" ,['text','barcode']%>
    </div> 
    <div class="field" id="barcode_type#{i}">
        <%= f.label "barcode_type#{i}" %>
        <%= f.text_field "barcode_type#{i}" %>
    </div> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please mention a reason too

Comment: Hello there, I am waiting for the reason, and not even my answer is wrong.

Comment: erm, i didnt downvote it. I have no idea who downvoted it

Comment: I am not asking you @leo277. I just want to know the reason by the one who downvoted it.